# Mock objects, database access objects, and transactional scope

Tags: java, unit-testing, transactions, mocking, graph-databases

I'm using easy mock to test some of my classes. They are pretty simplistic microservices; they read a message from a queue (a vertex id) and call a method. This method opens a transaction, accesses a vertex in the graph database, does some work on that vertex, and finally closes that transaction.

Here's an example method:

```
public void updateLocation(String s) {
    ReadWriteTransaction tx = GraphHolder.readWriteTransaction();
    tx.commit(() -> {
        User user = UserFactory.getUser(s, tx);
        if (user != null) {
            Location approxLocation = getMapApi().getLocationFromPhoneNumber(user.getPhone())
            user.setLocation(approxLocation);
        }
    });
}
```

This relies on an external API, something which should be mocked. I'm using EasyMock so the setup looks a bit like this:

```
public MapApi getMockedMapApi() {
    ReadWriteTransaction tx = GraphHolder.readWriteTransaction();
    return tx.commit(() -> {
        Location location = LocationFactory.createLocation(tx);
        location.setCity(CITY);
        MapApi mapApi = createMock(MapApi.class);
        expect(mapApi.getLocationFromPhoneNumber(PHONE_NUMBER)).andReturn(location);
        replay(mapApi);
        return mapApi;
    });
}
```

The problem with this approach is that the location object exists in a different transactional scope than that of the user object. Accessing or mutating any properties or adjacencies outside of the transactional scope throws an exception (which occurs with user.setLocation(approxLocation)).

I also tried to mock up the Location class and return a mocked location from the mocked mapsApi. The problem with this is that I can't set a mock location vertex as an adjacency to a real user vertex - our graph db library (tinkerpop3) throws an error when I try to do this (again, with user.setLocation(approxLocation)).

And unfortunately - changing the way transactions are handled is not a possibility.

Any ideas on the best solution to this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't `Location` be just a value object that can be instantiated with `new` and used independently of any transaction? It's seems weird that it  would *require* a transaction.

Comment: No, Location is a DAO. Location is also just an example, it would be perfectly valid to have a service which operates on a User or a Company DAO.

Answer (score 0):

Update your original `updateLocation(String s)` to inject `Location` object

Comment: This wouldn't make a difference, location objects can only exist within a transactional scope. That would shift the same issue to the method which creates a location.